# "Will patrons kindly note that this restaurant will be closed on 17 July." — Why is it possible to use inversion here without a question mark?

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion, rhetorical-questions

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patron):
**(1)** *Will patrons kindly note that this restaurant will be closed on 17 July*.

There is no question mark but the word order is inverted.
How to explain the presence of inversion here?
What sense does this sentence obtain, having the inverted word order?
What request do I need to type in Google to find the grammar topic with analogous examples?

Comment: 'Will' is an exhortation here, not a question. If it were a question, how would patrons answer it? With "No, we are coming in anyway" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question syntax is used to make certain requests more tentative, and hence more polite. There is a bit of a grey area, some requests might be questions:

> Will you (or "won't you") have a biscuit?

Some are more clearly instructions:

> Will you please leave my office

The expression "Will you note that ...."  is not intended as a question. It is a tentative (and hence polite) way of saying "Please note that...".  But as a rhetorical question, no answer is expected.  As a non-question, it is very common to leave this unpunctuated. But it would not be a mistake to add a question mark.

In speech, such a non-question often gets the falling intonation that is typical of statements, not requests.

Comment: You wrote about the expression "_Will you note that_ ...." the following: "As a rhetorical question, no answer is expected". Does it mean this expression is a rhetorical question or just has an analogous feature without being one?

Comment: in context I'd understand it to be a rhetorical question.  I would not respond to it with "Yes I will note it" or "No I won't note it"  No answer is expected.